# Maven resources not getting copied in jar file

Tags: java, maven, resources, pom.xml

My maven project has a parent POM as well as three children POM.
My parent POM looks like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupID</groupId>
<artifactId>artifacct</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>name</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>clojars.org</id>
        <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>finalName</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But the problem is my resources are not getting added to the jar file. What could be the possible problem with this ?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to clean project using mvn clean but it didn't worked. I am using mvn assembly:single to create my jar file.

Comment: That is not sufficient research effort.  Why are you expecting the resources to be picked up?  What Maven manual or guide did you follow?  Or did you just type gibberish and expect things to magically work?

Comment: Which modules are you trying to build the jar-with-dependencies for?  I'm not used to seeing assembly plugin configuration in the parent pom, so you might try moving it into the module(s) where you want to use it.

Comment: Give your child pom.xml files also... It would be better to analyze..

Answer (score 0):

do you use `maven-dependency-plugin` ?
something like this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and package you jar like this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>package.class.your.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```